# display json data letest record as per user id

Tags: android, json, chat, message

i wont to display the list of chats of clients.the data is come from json,
the  last message of chat is display on chat.but  it displays all message of all clients in list.like

[image]

here is my ListMessage.class activity

```
public class ListMessage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageButton btnFooter_Home, btnFooter_Message, btnFooter_Notification, btnFooter_More;
EditText textUser;
List<Msg_data> msgList;
ListView lv;
String uri = "http://staging.talentslist.com/api/user/23/chat";
LinearLayout linear_Home, linear_Message, linear_Notification, linear_More;
GlobalClass myGlog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_message);
    myGlog = new GlobalClass(getApplicationContext());
    setFooter();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    textUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUser);
    //       textUser.isFocused()
    boolean inConnected = myGlog.isNetworkConnected();
    if (inConnected) {
         requestData(uri);
    }

}

public void requestData(String uri) {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(uri,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    msgList = MsgJSONParser.parseData(response);
                    MsgAdapter adapter = new MsgAdapter(ListMessage.this, msgList);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(ListMessage.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
}
}
```

MsgAdapter.java class

```
public class MsgAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private List<Msg_data> nList;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> imageCache;
private RequestQueue queue;
String isread;

public MsgAdapter(Context context, List<Msg_data> list) {

    this.context = context;
    this.nList = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    imageCache = new LruCache<>(cacheSize);

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView __isread;
    TextView _username;
    TextView _detais;
    TextView _time;

    ImageView _image;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return nList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final Msg_data msg = nList.get(position);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    isread = msg.getIs_read();
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_notification, null);
        if (isread.equals("0")) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009999"));
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder._username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        holder._detais = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
        holder.__isread = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvplateform);
        holder._time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.createdTime);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder._username.setText(msg.getUser_name().toString());
    holder._detais.setText(msg.getMessage().toString());
    holder._time.setText(msg.getCreated_at().toString());
    //   holder.__isread.setText(notifi.getIs_read().toString());
    holder._image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gameImage);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(msg.getImage_link().toString())                     // Set image url
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)   // Cache for image
            .into(holder._image);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Msg_data.java class

```
public class Msg_data {
public int id;
public String user_id;
public String user_name;
public String message;
public String is_read;
public String image_link;
public String created_at;
public String from;
public String to;


public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}


public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public String getIs_read() {
    return is_read;
}

public void setIs_read(String is_read) {
    this.is_read = is_read;
}


public String getImage_link() {
    return image_link;
}

public void setImage_link(String image_link) {
    this.image_link = image_link;
}

public String getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

public Msg_data() {
}

public Msg_data(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

MsgJSONParser.java class

```
public class MsgJSONParser {
static List<Msg_data> notiList;

public static List<Msg_data> parseData(String content) {

    JSONArray noti_arry = null;
    Msg_data noti = null;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
        noti_arry = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        notiList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < noti_arry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = noti_arry.getJSONObject(i);

            //JSONObject obj = noti_arry.getJSONObject(i);
            noti = new Msg_data();

            noti.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
            noti.setMessage(obj.getString("message"));
            noti.setUser_name(obj.getString("user_name"));
            noti.setFrom(obj.getString("from"));
            noti.setTo(obj.getString("to"));
            noti.setCreated_at(obj.getString("created_at"));
            noti.setImage_link(obj.getString("image_link"));
            noti.setIs_read(obj.getString("is_read"));

            notiList.add(noti);
        }
        return notiList;

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

please give me  some idea what to do and how to do

Comment: I don't understand your question. Image cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i guess, you should  replace

```
msgList = MsgJSONParser.parseData(response);
MsgAdapter adapter = new MsgAdapter(ListMessage.this, msgList);
```

with

```
msgList = MsgJSONParser.parseData(response);
ArrayList<Msg_data> userList=new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<msgList.size();i++){
    if (!userList.contains(msgList.get(i)))
        userList.add(msgList.get(i));
    else {
        int index=userList.indexOf(msgList.get(i));
        if (userList.get(index).compareTo(msgList.get(i))>0)
            userList.add(msgList.get(i));
    }
}
MsgAdapter adapter = new MsgAdapter(ListMessage.this, userList);`
```

and implement Comparable and override equals method in your Msg_data class

```
public class Msg_data implements Comparable {
public int id;
public String user_id;
public String user_name;
public String message;
public String is_read;
public String image_link;
public String created_at;
public String from;
public String to;


public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}


public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public String getIs_read() {
    return is_read;
}

public void setIs_read(String is_read) {
    this.is_read = is_read;
}


public String getImage_link() {
    return image_link;
}

public void setImage_link(String image_link) {
    this.image_link = image_link;
}

public String getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

public Msg_data() {
}

public Msg_data(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
     try
{
    return (this.getUser_id().equals(( (Msg_data)obj).getUser_id()));
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
    return false;
    }
        }

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Object o) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("your pattern here");
    try {
        Date date=simpleDateFormat.parse(created_at);
        Date dateOtherObject=simpleDateFormat.parse(((Msg_data)o).getCreated_at());
        return  date.compareTo(dateOtherObject);
    }
    catch (ParseException e){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

something like this:) Dont forget replace simple date format in compare method

Comment: i tried this code ,but it give me error at `  if(!userList.contains(msgList.get(i)))` the error is: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"

Comment: one of userIds is null. You should add checks for nullable value